# Remove duplicates in summarize table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to remove duplicate rows of a union of two tables using DAX.

This is my code:

```
Global = 
VAR Table1= SUMMARIZE(GLAccounts;GLAccounts[AccountID];GLAccounts[AccountDescription];GLAccounts[Name];GLAccounts[GroupingCode];GLAccounts[ChaveConta])
Var Table2= SUMMARIZE(GLEntries;GLEntries[AccountID];GLEntries[AccountDescription];GLEntries[Name];GLEntries[GroupingCode];GLEntries[ChaveConta])
RETURN
UNION(Table1;Table2)
```

I know if I create another summarize table over this one, I'll remove the duplicates, but isn't there a way to do the whole thing in a single table?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just wrap the union with [`DISTNCT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/distinct-table-function-dax). It works as a table function as well as a column function.

```
DISTINCT(UNION(Table1;Table2))
```